# How do I make pygame load the images faster?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, performance, pygame

I'm trying to make a game using pygame and I need some character to move left and right. To do so, everytime the user holdds the "left" button, I draw the background image again, and I draw the character a bit to the left of it's previous position, and I do the similar action when he holds the "right" button. The problem is that the images do not load fast enough. When I run the code and hold the "left" button for example, the sprite does move left, but it seems to be gone for a tiny time (something like 0.2 seconds) and the movement is not continuous (By saying the sprite is gone, I mean there is a time where I could "pause" the screen and see only the background image, without the sprite). I want the movement to be continuous, as it does not look good right now. I've tried to update my clock tick, but for the sprite to move continously it has to move really slowly, and I don't want that too. Here's my code:

```
run = True

while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x = x-vel
        screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        screen.blit(ship_img, (x, y))
        pygame.display.flip()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x = x + vel
        screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        screen.blit(ship_img, (x, y))
        pygame.display.flip()
```

("vel" is a constant, in my code it's value is 5)

How do I fix that?

 The game I'm trying to make is [THIS](https://tasdikrahman.me/2016/02/02/Making-of-space-Shooter-using-pygame/) one, and if you scroll down you can see that this guy's spaceship moves continuously, so it is possible to do that.

Comment: Why is there a `pygame.display.flip()` after each `screen.blit`?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I think that's the problem yeah, so should I remove all of them expect for the one at the end?

Comment: A single `pygame.display.flip()` at the end of the main loop shod be sufficient.

Comment: you put link to spaceship game - go to this link, there is link to source code on github (look for `tasdikrahman/spaceShooter`) and you can see in source code how to write it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From the way your question is phrased it seems you want your playerobject to move seamlessly. If that's the case, there's a much better way to go about doing this!

First make a variable for the speed at which your playerobject moves on the x-axis.
If your playerobject is defined as a class, be sure to refer to it as self before the declaration.

```
speedx = 0
```

After that, replace all the code in the events with just changing the speed variable to whatever number you please.

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        speedx = insert number here
```

This is how I usually go about it. Hope it helps!

Comment: Also if you want to make things even easier to test, I'd create a gameloop so that you don't have to keep calling your pygame.display.flip(). If you make a gameloop function with all the basic game functions in there the pygame program will do most of that display update work for you.